# Translation of 魔法みたいあなたしか見えない全てが初めての私

Tags: translation

Last week I've stumbled upon a japanese song and have been struggling with the translation ever since. Here are the culprit lines:

> [連]{つ}れていって
>
> [知]{し}らない[世界]{せかい}
>
> ずっと[手]{て}を[放]{はな}さないで
>
> [魔法]{まほう}みたいあなたしか[見]{み}えない[全]{すべ}てが[初]{はじ}めての[私]{わたし}

So far I've come up with the following:

> Take me
>   [to] The unknown world
>   Never let go of my hand
>   Like magic, I can't see anything but you ... everything is?? ... the new me??

To a newbie like me this [全]{すべ}てが[初]{はじ}めての[私]{わたし} doesn't make a lot of sense in the given context (and [初]{はじ}めての[私]{わたし} by itself... "the first me"? "first time for me"? "the new me"?..). How should I interpret the last line of the song?

Comment: I think, but am not sure, that 全が初めて is a nominal phrase modifying 私, as in "me, for whom everything is new". あなたしか見えない is also modifying 私. You might have realized this but I think  魔法みたい might have a double meaning in "want to see" and "looks like".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I checked the lyrics on two different websites to find that, on both, there was a space after the 「魔法みたい」, which would mean that we need to treat it as an independent phrase.

> "It's like magic."

Lyrics: http://lyrics.jetmute.com/viewlyrics.php?id=274938

「あなたしか見えないすべてが初めての私」 is the Japanese equivalent of an English relative clause --- "A me who ~~~~~".  Everything that comes before 「私」 modifies 「私」.

> "A me who cannot see anything but you and to whom everything is new."

Comment: But in this case shouldn't there be some particle between 見えない and 初めて ?